# how to downgrade expo sdk version from 42 to 40.0.1?

Tags: sdk, expo

I would like to know how to downgrade expo sdk 42 to 40.0.1.
My original is 40.0.1, I upgraded to 42 but I face permission issues after upgrade. so I want to downgrade back.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

```
expo upgrade 40.0.1
```

It will downgrade your expo sdk and it works for my case.